# Criar um link ou banner em javascript usando outro javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu queria colocar um banner ou link em determinado local da página usando um javascript que ficaria em outro local da mesma página

tipo

```
<script>
função que eu colocaria os links ou banners
</script>

<div>
<script>
local que apareceria os links e/ou banner (não sei se precisaria de script aqui)
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Você não precisa de duas _tags_ `script`, faz tudo em uma só. E para aparecer os "links", seria no HTML, seria isso que você quer?

Comment: nao tem que ser separada, é para um blog o script ficaria fora e dentro das postagens eu to colocando um link com um modal e nesse modal eu colocaria esse link igual para todas as postagens... mais se caso eu querer trocar o link era só ir no javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu vai precisar da função js que adiciona o elemento ou html que tu precisa:

```
 <script>
    function adicionarLink(){
        document.getElementById("div-inserir-link").innerHTML = "<a href='http://google.com.br'>Google</a>";
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        adicionarLink();
    }, false);
 </script>
```

a função do onload só vai chamar a função de adição, mas tu pode fazer no onlick de algum elemento, ou em qulquer outro momento.

E seu html:

```
<div id='div-inserir-link'></div>
```

Comment: não deu certo não, eu coloquei o script em tudo qualquer lugar mais no div nao apareceu o link =/

Comment: @Lary, editei a resposta. Testa agora. (=

Comment: agora sim rsrs, muito obrigada @Aline

Comment: Sobre o que o Douglas comentou na sua postagem, é isso mesmo. Você não deve ter tags `<script>` espalhadas pelo seu código. O Ideal é que esses js fiquem até em um arquivo .js, nem no mesmo arquivo que o HTML, imagine então sobre estarem espalhados em todo o HTML. É uma prática bem ruim. Você pode ler um pouco sobre isso aqui: https://mauricioszabo.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/unobtrusive-javascript/

Comment: mas no caso vai ser um script só que vou usar e as tags div nas postagens